# Use Javascript to make numbers accend

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random

How would I use this code to make digits flip clock digits appear in accending order, instead of randomly?

```
$( '.count' ).flip( Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) );

setInterval(function(){
$( '.count' ).flip( Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) );
}, 1000);
```

Thank you, Much appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by removing the `Math.random()` if you'd like to get rid of the randomness :)

Comment: hint: you might like to remember in a variable what the current value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would store the number in a variable like this

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    update();

    setInterval(function(){
        update();
    }, 1000);
    function update() {
        $( '.count' ).flip( count );
        count++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, works great, would this account for double digits tho?

Comment: An integer is just a number, so yes double digits work too. All the way up to 9007199254740992!

Comment: Ok great, thank you, I will implement later tonight(Central Africa time) haha, and provide you with feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
var count = 0;
update();
setInterval(update, 1e3);
function update() {
    $( '.count' ).flip( count++ );
}
```

But if you want to be able to stop `setInterval`, use

```
var count = 0, timer = setInterval(update, 1e3);
update();
function update() {
    $( '.count' ).flip( count++ );
    if(stopCond) clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also correct, it needs to tick over to infinty basically, not stop. I want to give you a correct answer aswell, but only able to use one answer as correct?

Comment: @JoshWade you can only have one accepted answer on StackOverflow. you can support him by up-voting his answer though.

Comment: you also need atleast 15 Rep to vote up :/

Comment: i am quite new to stackoverflow & web dev

Comment: @JoshWade just upvoted your question for you, welcome to the +15rep club lol

Comment: YAY! haha 15 and counting